# Trouble using a reusable database connector

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm new to php. I've been having trouble connecting to and using a data with PHP. I don't really have much information on the issue, maybe I'm using some out of date method, or I did something wrong. I've double checked and looked on this website for information, but I didn't find much. Here's the code below.

The error reads :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\Practice\mysqli\pdo.php on line 6

That would mean that there is a problem located near the

```
$result = $conn->query($sql)or die(mysqli_error());
```

I entered my username and password correctly. I even created a new username and password just to make sure. I have no other ideas why $conn isn't working, and I would love any thoughts or ideas on the issue!

connection.ini.php

```
function dbConnect($usertype, $connectiontype = 'pdo') {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'student';
    if ($usertype == 'read') {
        $user = 'user';
        $pwd = 'pass';
    }

    elseif ($usertype == 'write') {
        $user = 'root';
        $pwd = 'password';
    }
    else {
        exit('Unrecognized connection type');
    }
    //Connection Code
    if ($connectionType ='mysqli') {
        return new mysqli($host, $user, $pwd, $db) or die ('Cannot open database');
        } 
else {

        try {
            return new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db, $user, $pwd');
        }
        catch(PDOExecption $e) {
            echo 'Cannot connect to database';
            exit;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

mysqli.php

```
?php
require_once('connection.inc.php');
$conn = dbConnect('read', 'pdo');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM guestbook';

$result = $conn->query($sql)or die(mysqli_error());
$numRows = $result->num_rows;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<p> A total of <?php
echo $numRows;
?>
records were found.</p>
</html>
```

Comment: You've got an assignment in your conditional there.  `if ($connectionType ='mysqli')`  Need 2 equals signs.

Comment: To elaborate, that's making the clause within the conditional block execute _always_.  What's more, I don't think you can combine return and or in the manner you're expecting.  In PHP the operators always return their boolean value, as opposed to other languages where the value of the last expression is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you get the...

> *"Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean"*

...it is likely because there is an issue with your query. The `prepare()` might return `FALSE` (a Boolean), but this generic failure message doesn't leave you much in the way of clues. How do you find out what is wrong with your query? You *ask*!

First of all, make sure error reporting is turned on and visible: add these two lines to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

If your error reporting has been set in the php.ini you won't have to worry about this. Just make sure you handle errors gracefully and never reveal the true cause of any issues to your users. Revealing the true cause to the public can be a gold engraved invitation for those wanting to harm your sites and servers. If you do not want to send errors to the browser you can always monitor your web server error logs. Log locations will vary from server to server e.g., on Ubuntu the error log is typically located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. If you're examining error logs in a Linux environment you can use `tail -f /path/to/log` in a console window to see errors as they occur in real-time....or as you make them.

Once you're squared away on standard error reporting adding error checking on your database connection and queries will give you much more detail about the problems going on. Have a look at this example where the column name is incorrect. First, the code which returns the generic fatal error message:

```
$sql = "SELECT `foo` FROM `weird_words` WHERE `definition` = ?";
$query = $mysqli->prepare($sql)); // assuming $mysqli is the connection
$query->bind_param('s', $definition);
$query->execute();
```

The error is generic and not very helpful to you in solving what is going on.

With a couple of more lines of code you can get very detailed information which you can use to solve the issue *immediately*. Check the `prepare()` statement for truthiness and if it is good you can proceed on to binding and executing.

```
$sql = "SELECT `foo` FROM `weird_words` WHERE `definition` = ?";
if($query = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) { // assuming $mysqli is the connection
    $query->bind_param('s', $definition);
    $query->execute();
    // any additional code you need would go here.
} else {
    $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
    echo $error; // 1054 Unknown column 'foo' in 'field list'
}
```

If something is wrong you can spit out an error message which takes you directly to the issue. In this case there is no `foo` column in the table, solving the problem is trivial.

If you choose, you can include this checking in a function or class and extend it by handling the errors gracefully as mentioned previously.

Comment: That worked, I got a better explanation of my problem. The error says something along the lines of " no such host is known" so atleast I'm closer to finding an answer